# Вопрос по длине ссылок в robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Уважаемое сообщество, есть такая проблема, google ругается, что всего 5000 знаков можно.
В файле ссылки вида:

```
Disallow: /details/item/ba6e2323/a8b55303336303/a3af6373733303.html

Disallow: /details/item/ba6e2323/a8b55303336303/a3af6373733304.html

Disallow: /details/item/ba6e2323/a8b55303336303/a3af6373733305.html
```

**Собственно вопрос**: можно ли как то сделать ссылки что-то вроде:

```
Disallow: */a3af6373733303.html
```

чтобы уменьшить количество символов?

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно.  
В robots.txt допускаются спецсимволы:  
**\*** любое количество символов, в том числе 0.  
**\$** конец адресной строки

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать.